# My second year garlic has flowers. Is it safe to eat?

Tags: harvesting, root-vegetables, garlic

Apparently I didn't find all my garlic bulbs last fall and they grew to 4 feet tall this spring.  They have a large, white flower head.  I want to try cooking with it, but don't want to risk my family's health.Does anyone know if the different parts of the plant are edible?  Also, would the bulbs be good for food?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From what I gather garlic flowers are safe to eat. From [this site](http://www.pots2plots.com/growing%20Edible%20Flowers.htm):

> **Alliums** (leeks, chives, garlic, garlic chives):  All parts of these plants are edible. The flowers tend to be stronger flavoured than the leaves. Suitable for salads, in egg dishes such as omelettes and in soups.

Also see the wikipedia entry on [garlic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic)

> Other parts of the garlic plant are
>   also edible. The leaves and flowers
>   (bulbils) on the head (spathe) are
>   sometimes eaten. They are milder in
>   flavor than ...

Here's also [a post by someone on gardenweb](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/load/allium/msg0620170428338.html) who was answering the question of what is edible in garlic:

> ... the entire thing is edible.
>   That includes the scape itself, the
>   spathe, and the bubils inside the
>   spathe. However, if you let them go
>   too long they toughen up and turn
>   woody; and are generally inedible that
>   way. Try and break them off no later
>   than when they first curl. If they've
>   straighened out, then still break them
>   off, for the sake of bulb development.
>   But don't bother trying to eat them.

Comment: The bulb just before it flowers -- including the stalk -- is called the scape.  It not only edible, but delicious, I frequently buy it from my farmer's market and make pesto of it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, garlic flowers are delicious. Pull the petals off and use them in your cooking. We generally put them in salads, on steaks, in rice or mashed potatoes.. Etc.